# Use `tail` to rotate nginx logs in order have a single log file capped in size

Tags: nginx, tail, log-rotation

Can use `tail` to rotate a nginx log file **in orderer to have a single log file** capped in size?

```
tail -c 1000000 access.log > temp.log
mv temp.log access.log
kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
```

The above would be executed in a cron job (running every 5 minutes) every time `access.log` exceeds `1100000` bytes.

The last line tells nginx to reopen log files (as the second line deletes the original `access.log`)

I've read about variuos methods to rotate (nginx) logs but I've never read about this approach.

This way I end up having a single file capped in size.

And rotation is not applied to a set of files but to the log entries inside a single log file.

Of course `tail -c` (as from comments) will truncate the first (oldest line).

The major issue with that is that while tail is writing the truncate file the process is still writing log entries so some entries ***may*** get lost.

---

**Bottom note:**

I'm aware of `logrotate` and `newsyslog` tools, I've read the main parts of the documentation and they are also trivial to setup for ordinary scenarios.

My attempt is not to reinvent the wheel. I'm just "curious" to know if things can be done in a different way.

The answer probably is **no** for very good reasons.

I'm just trying to have a better understanding on the subject.

Comment: Why have you decided not to use logrotate?

Comment: If you use `-c` there, you will get broken lines.

Comment: Terrible. Application keeps writing to the (still open) filehandle for the (deleted but still open) `access.log` and the disk fills up mysteriously until in confusion the system is rebooted or (hopefully) someone knows something about `lsof` and how to setup proper logrotation.

Comment: @thrig you're right. however nginx provides a way to reopen log files, I updated the question.

Comment: @Tim It's just a question... Probably I'll go with logrotate, or newsyslog (since in this case I'm on mac OS). However I was looking for a solution that let me keep a single file with the last `x` MB of logs instead of a set of rotating files.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen only the first (oldest) line will be truncated. I can live with that.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/291368/log-rotation-of-stdout#291397 may be of some interest

Comment: Actually I became a friend of logrotate. It's a nice tool you already have on your system, created just for this purpose. It's a standard solution so another system administrator knows how to handle your setup. The configuration can be hold in a specific file (e.g. /etc/logrotate.d/nginx) so your configuration can be managed by Puppet, Chef or whatever. Using a wrench to bang in a nail might be a solution if you don't have a hammer.